# Using "not in" on WHERE with AND?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get a better understanding of how "not in" works with WHERE in MySQL.

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM current_mailing_list 
WHERE address1 NOT IN
    (select address1 from old_mailing_list) AND
    city not in (select city from old_mailing_list);
```

In the above example, the purpose of the query is to list mailing addresses which are new. `address1` is a street address such as `1234 N. Main St`. The problem happens when `1234 N. Main St` occurs in more than one city, which can happen. So I decided to add `city` to it to make it more unique.

My question is, is this doing what I expect it to do? Meaning, it should find those street addresses (address1) that don't exist in the `old_mailing_list` **AND** then make sure they have a different `city`.

I have done this, just with the address1:

```
SELECT * FROM current_mailing_list 
WHERE address1 NOT IN 
    (select address1 from old_mailing_list);
```

and it produced a much larger list (about 10 times the size). So I wanted to add `city` to this. Or is my logic in the entirely wrong and need another approach?

Comment: Wouldn't a `NOT EXISTS` be better here?

Comment: @Edward If one of the answers posted helped, please accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use `NOT IN`, you'll want to combine both the city and address in the same clause as MySQL supports this (other RDBMS do not support this method). As others have pointed out, you won't get your desired results using both separately.

Try this if you want to use `NOT IN`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM current_mailing_list 
WHERE (address1,city) NOT IN  
   (select address1, city from old_mailing_list);
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/45baab/2)

I prefer to use a `LEFT JOIN` for this personally though and check for NULL:

```
SELECT c.* 
FROM current_mailing_list c
    LEFT JOIN old_mailing_list o ON c.address1 = o.address1 AND c.city = o.city
WHERE o.address1 IS NULL
```

Answer (score 6):

Your current query will not return new addresses where EITHER their "address1" or "city" appears *at all* in the old mailing list. I think you want to select cities where they don't *both appear together*, like so:

```
SELECT *
FROM current_mailing_list c
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM old_mailing_list
    WHERE
        address1 = c.address1
        AND city = c.city
)
```

Quite literally; select everything from the current mailing list where there is no record in the old mailing list with the same city and address1.

Answer (score 1):

If 1234 N. Main St. is an address for both a city in the old mailing list and a city in the new mailing list, your query will exclude BOTH addresses. Your query is doing exactly what it says it's doing: you will get addresses where *both* the street address and the city are *not* in the old mailing list. If *either* appear for an address in the old mailing list, that address will not be retrieved.